# Mac indexed search of a SMB connected mount?

Tags: mac, file-sharing, iis, server-message-block, indexing

Is there any free or inexpensive software, such as "advanced network search," "IBM Omnisearch," "Google search appliance," that will provide a web page in which our mac users can instant search our SMB windows server 2003 shared drive? PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.ostafiev.com/ifs/
Is that a good one?

Comment: http://www.softperfect.com/products/searchengine/ Is this a good one?